Postfix alias vs. virtual_alias for catch-everything-else?
I have postfix running fine with aliases. So I got an email alias1@ex.dom mapped to my local user user@ex.dom. Same for alias2 and so on.
Unknown users (or aliases) get blocked by postifx.
Now I want to implement a "catch-everything-else" mapping so postfix picks up all emails and delivers them for existing aliases/users to the local mailboxes while it should deliver evrything else (like nosuchuser@ex.dom) to a deidcated local user.
I tried with
@ex.dom catch@ex.dom

in /etc/postfix/virtual (and enabled virtual_alias_maps).
It worked. But in the way it delivered ALL mail to the catch-user. Which is not what it should do.
I know alias is for local delivery while virtual is for pre-local delivery. Is it not possible to create such a ruleset?
Thanks!
/KNEBB
